# What are the Standard Model predictions for the couplings of the $Z$ boson to $b$ quarks?

Tags: particle-physics, standard-model, quarks, bosons

What are the Standard Model predictions for both the vector and axial-vector couplings of the $Z$ boson to $b$ quarks ($g_V^b$ and $g_A^b$)?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This is but a blunt plugin in the expression of your [PDG](https://pdg.lbl.gov/2019/reviews/rpp2019-rev-standard-model.pdf), (10.2), (10.5), no?
$$
g_V=-1/2 + 2/3 \sin^2\theta_W, \qquad g_A=-1/2 .
$$

Comment: And is there any SM prediction for $\sin{\theta_W}$?

Comment: Mea culpa, squared, fixed. The SM does not predict $\theta_W$, so it is determined by experiment. Table 10.2 in the PDG gives you several values, all around 0.23 for the square of the sine.